# Rails admin parse the ckeditor , and now the code shows in the list

Tags: ckeditor, rails-admin

Hi i am using rails admin and when i added the ckeditor which was very nice in the project but the problem was when i was saving it it looks like the code is parse as well

[image]

as you can see in the rails admin it is just text and when it is saved the output is codes and it should not do that any body here that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out rails  do the security measures and now parse it i just did this

```
<%=raw %>
```

and now it returns that shows the code instead of code